# Append list in dictionary through dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, append, dictionary-comprehension

Here is my example:

```
sample_dict = {'foo':[1], 'bar': [2]}
{el: sample_dict[el].append(3) for el in sample_dict.keys()}
```

it generates:

```
{'foo': None, 'bar': None}
```

while I am expecting this:

```
{'foo': [1,3], 'bar': [2,3]}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `append` returns `None`, not the list.

Comment: `{k: v + [3] for k, v in sample_dict.items()}` — But there's really little reason to use a dict comprehension here over a regular loop.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this way:

```
    {el: sample_dict[el]+[3] for el in sample_dict.keys()}
```

Generates expected output